# Seasonality and non-stationarity

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality

It is usually claimed that a time series  with seasonality is not stationary and requires seaosnal differencing. Intuitively, this could be understood by the fact that the mean is time-dependent.

Now, in analogy with AR(1) models, I can write down the following process:

$y_t = \phi y_{t-12}+ \epsilon_t$

Assume that $\phi <1$.
In which sense is this process not stationary?

Also, does this imply that modeling with the above model ($\text{SARMA}(0,0,0)(1,0,0)_{12}$) will never make sense (as $D=0$)?

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: This model partitions the times into 12 disjoint groups but it doesn't specify *anything* about how those groups might be related.  Thus it cannot be said whether your process is stationary or not; indeed, it isn't even defined.

Comment: SARIMA(p,d,q)(P,0,Q) is a perfectly valid model, and yours is a special case. Differencing is justified when there is a unit root (seasonal differencing ~ seasonal unit root); otherwise it causes more problems than it is supposed to solve.

Comment: @whuber I don't think I follow you, sorry. Could you elaborate or provide a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Your model tells us something about $(\ldots, y_{-12},y_0,y_{12},y_{24},\ldots)$ and -- completely separately from that -- something about $(\ldots, y_{-11},y_1,y_{13},y_{25},\ldots),$ *but (apart from the common parameter $\phi$) it makes no assumptions whatsoever about how those two processes are related.*  It could be the case, for instance, that all the $y_{12t}$ have zero means and all the $y_{12t+1}$ have means of $10^6.$ Equivalently, you could take 12 totally different AR(1) processes with parameter $\phi$ and interleave them.

Comment: @RichardHardy so you wouldn't automarically apply seasonal differencing whenever you observe a seasonal pattern? In manuals such as https://otexts.com/fpp2/ it is claimed that "ime series with trends, or with seasonality, are not stationary" and it seems to me that the authors suggest seasonal differencing to remove any seasonality.

Comment: I don't think they suggest that! There is a reason why `auto.arima` (an algorithm created by the author of FPP) tests for the need for seasonal differencing rather than doing it automatically. I have noticed that the bad practice of overdifferencing is becoming widespread and I can only wonder where it is coming from.

Comment: @whuber I think I more o less see your point. Would something of the form $y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} +\phi_2 y_{t-12} +\epsilon_t$ (with no unit roots) make more sense to you then? The motivation of my question is actually very practical: should one always perform seasonal differencing when a seasonal pattern is present?

Comment: To answer your latter question, no, definitely not. Just like you do not difference every AR(1) process, you should not difference every SARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0) process. Only when there is a unit root is differencing justified. (There can be some "if"s and "but"s regarding when the drawbacks of overdifferencing are outweighed by robustness to structural breaks and such, but for a beginner, this should be the way to think.)

Comment: @RichardHardy is you look at the examples on section 8.9 you can read things like: "The data are clearly non-stationary, with some seasonality, so we will first take a seasonal difference. " or "The data are strongly seasonal and obviously non-stationary, so seasonal differencing will be used."  (https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html). Maybe I'm interpreting it wrongly, but the line of though: seasonality -> non-stationarity  -> seasonal differencing  is implicit in those statements and the procedure carried out for the examples

Comment: @RichardHardy but a AR(1) process can be stationary (so differencing is not justified a priori), while a seasonal pattern is usually claimed to imply non-stationarity. That is where my confusion comes from.

Comment: Your modified process is an example of an AR(12) model.  Assuming the $\varepsilon_t$ are *iid* with finite variance, then, it must be stationary.

Comment: As whuber said correctly, the seasonal process you have, SARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0), is stationary. The line of thought you cite is misleading. I do not believe thay mean it, but their phrasing may be poor so that it makes the impression it makes.